# Overriding the Equals in Scala

Tags: scala

I need to have a custom equal method for a few of case classes. After some online searching, I haven't see any definite solution. Shall I write my own method of equality check?

Comment: I'd advise you to consider your design carefully - if you need custom equality then a `case class` is rarely appropriate. If you just want to make the fields publicly accessible you can do that with an ordinary `class` using `val` or `var` declarations: `class MyClass(val x: Int, val y: String, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will need to define your own `equals` method:

```
case class Person(...) {

    override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = {
        ...
    }

    override def hashCode: Int = {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `equals` method looks easy, but it could also be trick. I strongly advise you to read the following chapter of Scala Cookbook about how to [Define an equals Method (Object Equality)](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch04s16.html) and this essay at Artima: [How to Write an Equality Method in Java](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question is about case classes. To my online search, it is not the same as class. The equals which is "==" in case class is generated by the compiler.

Comment: Yes. The compiler generates them **if you don't**. But, if you do, like the answer shows, the compiler won't generate it.